# Using JQuery inside a boxy modal

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a site which has a modal window (using boxy) with a form. Inside document ready I have the following to load up the modal window:

```
$("#confirm").boxy({title: "Title", modal: true});
```

Where the link is:

```
<a id="confirm" href="/confirm/">Confirm order</a>
```

And this runs fine where /confirm/ loads up a new html in the modal window.

But in the modal window I want to do some JQuery manipulations. But even simple things don't work. For example:

```
$("#link").click(function () {
  console.log('logging...');
});
```

Where "link" is the id on a link in the modal window, but when I click the link nothing happens. If I comment out the top and bottom lines (only have the console.log line it DOES log to the console...)

Everything works fine if I run this in a separate window. Am I missing something obvious?

Regards,
AndriJan

Answer (score 1):

Please use live function at the same time, target the id of the "a href" youre using...

```
$("#confirm").live('click', function () {
  console.log('logging...');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience working with this plugin. But try adding your binding in the `afterShow` callback and see if it works. If it works, then there is an issue in the plugin that prevents from working your onload event